# Thoughts on TUDBC

Tags: database, database-connection

Has anyone used [TUDBC](http://www.tudbc.org/)? This looks interesting, but I wonder how valuable it would be for me to investigate. I'm curious about anyone's good or bad experience.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to it.  I wasn't aware of its existence - I can't offer help on it beyond the obvious, such as "it is GPL licenced, so if GPL is not good for you, neither is TUDBC".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a solution looking for a problem.  Yes, it sounds great but I'm not going to use Java w/ TUDBC.  I'll stick with the "standard" of JDBC.